# PHP header not working

Tags: php

I have a web page that will get the data using POST method from the other page and then store the data to the database. After it's done, I want it to go back to the page where the data comes from. I used header(). But it didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
$spent = $_POST['spent'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$dbc = mysqli_connect('oniddb.cws.oregonstate.edu', 'chentao-db', 'BUU3UuwwGfwt7hxV', 'chentao-db') 
    or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT Total FROM Expense  E ORDER BY E.Index DESC LIMIT 1";  
//get the total
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysql_error()); 
$total = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);  
$total = $total['Total'] + $spent;  
$query = "INSERT INTO Expense (Date, Spent, Total, Description) VALUES ('$date', '$spent', '$total', '$description')";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($dbc);
header("Location: fetchData.php");
```

?>

What's wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: How does it fail? No errors? No strange behaviour? No nothing?

Comment: Is the previous page `fetchData.php`?

Comment: try to use a full path `http://domain.com/fetchData.php`

Comment: Remove the closing `?>` from your code and try again. You probably have an extra line after the `?>`.

Comment: **Go through this post it will help you :**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would work something like this

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/fetchData.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to place

```
 ob_start();
```

at top of your file..

Or you can try

```
 header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFRER']);

 die;
```

don't forget to place die at last.

Answer (score -1):

If your first query does not return any result, then the execution fails at this line:

```
$total = $total['Total'] + $spent;
```

Check if the first query has any results like this:

```
if(isset($total['Total'])){
   $total = $total['Total'] + $spent;
}
else {
   $total = $spent;
}
```

Comment: "Maybe" cannot be an answer.